# GoogleMap :GeoCoder Service (using location) for multiple position binding last content for all marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a google map to show multiple position on it. I am expecting the data come from any service source (Here I am hardcoded it for the time being). The content of the last position is binding with all the marker . I have been gone through all the discussion given here , but not able to get the solution .

Here is my Code :

```
var LocationArray = [
                 [ 26.864981300000000000, 80.962066000000050000],
                 [12.971598700000000000,77.594562699999980000],
                 [19.017614700000000000,72.856164400000010000],
                 [ 28.635308000000000000, 77.224960000000010000],
                 [ 13.060422000000000000, 80.249583000000030000],
                 [ 22.572646000000000000, 88.363894999999950000]
               ];
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    
  }
function showMultiplePostionOnMap(mapOptions,LocationArray){    
    var MapObjectForShowMultiplePostionOnMap =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MapAreaNode"), mapOptions);    
    var infowindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow();   
     for( var i = 0; i < LocationArray.length; i++){        
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            icon:image,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP           
        });
        marker.setMap(MapObjectForShowMultiplePostionOnMap);
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(LocationArray[i][0], LocationArray[i][1]));   
        if(parseInt((LocationArray.length)/2)==i)
        {
            MapObjectForShowMultiplePostionOnMap.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(LocationArray[i][0], LocationArray[i][1]));
        }           
        var infocor = new google.maps.LatLng(LocationArray[i][0], LocationArray[i][1]);     
        var add;
        geocoder.geocode({'location':infocor}, function(results, status)
        {       
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            add=results[0].formatted_address;
        }
        });     
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker,i) {        
            return function(){  
                infowindow.setContent(add);
                infowindow.open(MapObjectForShowMultiplePostionOnMap,marker);
            }
        })(marker,i));                         
     }


}
```

I think its a repeated question , but I have tried a lot but not able to get any solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include `add` into the self-executing function, `add` will be overwritten by each geocode-response.

Possible solution(adds the `add`-property to the marker):

```
var infocor = new google.maps.LatLng(LocationArray[i][0], LocationArray[i][1]); 

(function(marker,infocor){
  geocoder.geocode({'location':infocor}, function(results, status) {  
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      marker.add=results[0].formatted_address;
    }
  });  
})(marker,infocor);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
  if(this.add) { //geocoding was successfull   
    infowindow.setContent(this.add);
    infowindow.open(MapObjectForShowMultiplePostionOnMap,this);
  }
});
```